# Using AsyncTask pushProgress() to update a ListView

Tags: java, android

I have made an activity that should be populated with Mr. Sharkey's [SeperatedListAdapter](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) . The thing is, everything works if I try to create the whole list at once. But what I'm doing is running an AsyncTask that loops through a quite long process and for each section pushes some progress to a function, that in turn updates the adapter. Something like this:

```
    public SeparatedListAdapter adapter;
    private ListView list;

    public Map<String, String> createItem(String title, String caption,
            String uri) {
        Map<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item.put(ITEM_TITLE, title);
        item.put(ITEM_CAPTION, caption);
        item.put(ITEM_URI, uri);
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(getBaseContext());
list = new ListView(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        this.setContentView(list);

}

private class FileLoadingThread extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Void> {
private LinkedList<Object[]> sections = new LinkedList<Object[]>();
    private MainAction activity;
public boolean hasItems() {
        return !sections.isEmpty();
    }

    public LinkedList<Object[]> getItems() {
        return sections;
    }
[..]
protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {
[..]
List<Map<String, String>> security = new LinkedList<Map<String, String>>();
                        publishProgress(new Object[] { "Title",
                                security });
[..]

}

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... value) {
                    sections.add(value);
            activity.updateAdapter(value);
        }
[..]
}
protected void updateAdapter(Object[] value) {

        try {
            List<Map<String,?>> security2 = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();  
            security2.add(createItem("Remember passwords", "Save usernames and passwords for Web sites","Save usernames and passwords for Web sites"));  
            security2.add(createItem("Clear passwords", "Save usernames and passwords for Web sites","Save usernames and passwords for Web sites"));  
            security2.add(createItem("Show security warnings", "Show warning if there is a problem with a site's security","Save usernames and passwords for Web sites"));  
            adapter.addSection(""+Math.random(), new SimpleAdapter(this, security2, R.layout.list_complex,  
                    new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption }));  
            Log.v(TAG, "Tried pushing to UI" + value[0]);
            /*adapter.addSection((String) value[0], new SimpleAdapter(

                    getBaseContext(), (List<Map<String, ?>>) value[1],
                    R.layout.list_complex, new String[] { ITEM_TITLE,
                            ITEM_CAPTION },
                    new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title,
                            R.id.list_complex_caption }));
                            */
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
protected void preUpdateAdapter() {
    ListIterator<Object[]> itr = mTask.getItems().listIterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        updateAdapter(itr.next());
    }
}
```

The thing is, this pushing works ok, for the first item, and after that, each header item throws this error:

```
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at com.example.SeparatedListAdapter.getView(SeparatedListAdapter.java:93)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1428)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1801)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:671)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:728)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1633)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1279)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7321)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7321)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7321)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7321)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1217)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1991)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
03-16 15:42:32.225: E/ListView(1410):   ... 27 more
```

The thing is, that when I push any number of updates from the `onCreate()` method, everything works great, but when I try to push them like this, they just fail. I can't for the life of me figure this out.

I first though that something in the received data was causing this, but as you can see, even with entirely normal data, this fails somewhy. Help?

**EDIT**

It seems, that the error arises, when somehow, the `convertView` at Mr. Sharkeys SeparatedListAdapter:80 becomes of type `android.widget.LinearLayout@4052b058`, which, as far as I can tell, should never happen. How is this possible?

**EDIT2**

This is becoming more interesting. What I previously omitted, but now included is, that I'm also saving the found objects, to be added as a batch later, so that on rotation the UI can be updated quickly without having to rerun the thread. So, if I disable the pushing to the UI thread, and instead rotate the device, they all load up nicely, and there are no errors thrown, but as you can see, the batch is using the exact same method to push these updates. Truly stumped!

**EDIT3**

I seem to have found a way to fix this. I am unsure if this is the right, or the only way to fix this, but hey - it seems to work!

In Mr. Sharkey's [code](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) I added changed the `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method to this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int sectionnum = 0;
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

            // check if position inside this section
            if(position == 0){ 
                convertView=null;
                return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);}

            if(position < size){ convertView=null;
            return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);}

            // otherwise jump into next section
            position -= size;
            sectionnum++;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The 2 `convertView=null;` statements may not seem much, but they made this thing work. Could anyone tell me why something that is not null or a `TextView` could be passed to this method?